# Interaction.CallByName in not working after Vb.net to C# migration

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration

We have a legacy  Vb.net library.
Need to incorporate this in .net 5 ,
so first we  convert to  c# (.net framework 4.6.1 )  using SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter
But its throwing below error if we access a property of object accessed after CallByName.
Its still using the VB.net Interaction.CallByName.

object does not contain a definition for Amount and no accessible extension method Amount  accepting a first argument of type object could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Can anybody faced this after migrating from Vb.net. Can we get rid of the vb.net  library and replace this with c# , reason is we need to convert this library to .NET 5 finally.
any pointer or suggestions on this
Please find the vb.net code and converted c# code below

```
 //VB.NEt Code
```

Private Function GetDetails(ByVal objEntity As Object, ByVal entityType As EntityTypeEnum) As Integer
Dim sumInsured As Integer

```
        Try
            Select Case EntityTypeEnum
                Case EntityTypeEnum.Type1
                    Dim targetEntity As Object = CallByName(objEntity, System.Enum.GetName(GetType(EntityPropertyEnum), EntityPropertyEnum.Type1), CallType.Get)
                    If targetEntity IsNot Nothing Then
                        targetAmount = targetEntity.Amount
                    End If
                    
                    
                    
                    
    //C# Code   after migration             
    private static int GetDetails(object objEntity, EntityTypeEnum entityType)
    {
        var sumInsured = default(int);
        try
        {
            switch (EntityTypeEnum)
            {
                case EntityTypeEnum.Type1:
                    {
                        var targetEntity = Interaction.CallByName(objEntity, Enum.GetName(typeof(EntityPropertyEnum), EntityPropertyEnum.Type1), CallType.Get);
                        if (targetEntity is object)
                        {
                            targetAmount = Conversions.ToInteger(targetEntity.Amount);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: I would say the problem probably based around GetDetails(object objEntity.  You're going to find the C# definition of object a whole heap more restrictive.  Maybe casting the object to the correct type might work, maybe using "dynamic" instead of object or maybe reflection or maybe rework your GetDetails method to be generic

Comment: Declare 'targetEntity' as 'dynamic' and change "if (targetEntity is object)" to "if (targetEntity != null)".

Comment: Any particular reason that the VB won't work in .NET 5?  Also, as a general rule, if you want to spot potential trouble for a conversion, `Option Strict On` is a good idea, it will remove a lot of the "do what I think the developer means" convenience shortcuts from VB that don't exist in C#.